# When to present NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nserror

I have a general question-  what are some guidelines for handling NSError's? For instance, `NSJSONSerialization` can return an error creating JSON objects or JSON data.

I feel like it's (maybe) not appropriate to alert the user in this case? But the error message is still important.

So I'm not sure when and where the best place to handle obscure, non-user related errors?

Comment: You can pop up an `UIAlertView` saying that "communication with the web service failed. Please contact the developer" or something.

Comment: Errors thrown internally should be handled internally.  Your users neither know why your app is throwing an error, why you decided to show them an error, or how to resolve it, so you should never show it to them.  If you can't handle an error (a fatal exception, say), then crash "gracefully".  Just don't bother anybody with a problem that you should have handled yourself, but couldn't because you under tested your app.

Comment: I don't think it hurts to pop up a number or error string, and request that that be reported to the developer.  You shouldn't expect/require it to be reported, though.  What you SHOULD do, if your app is something that might be considered important by the user, is use one of the available reporting mechanisms such as Flurry to report the error (and whatever additional info you can collect) to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the context in which error is thrown.

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html):

> **Recover if Possible or Display the Error to the User**
>
> The best user experience is for your app to recover transparently from
>   an error. If you’re making a remote web request, for example, you
>   might try making the request again with a different server.
>   Alternatively, you might need to request additional information from
>   the user such as valid username or password credentials before trying
>   again.

So, there are cases, where you would want error to be obscured from user with potential **fall back on error recovery path**.

And there are cases, where you would want to **let user know of the error occurred** and take a corrective measure.

At the same time, in many situations, as a programmer we want to **log error on console** so we could fix them while testing.

As a side note, there are plenty of cases where we throw custom `NSError` objects and handle them with alerts, logging or other ways!

It is worth going through the shared Apple Documentation link, I believe!